# Multicolor Column Headings with R's htmlTable

Tags: r

I wish to have multi-color columns in an htmlTable.

I want the company column to be red and the value column to be blue. How do I do that?

```
library("htmlTable")
library("tidyverse")

tibble(
  company = c("A", "B"),
  value = c(1, 2)
) %>% 
  addHtmlTableStyle(css.cell = "color: blue;") %>% 
  htmlTable(rnames = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
library("htmlTable")
library("tidyverse")

tibble(
  company = c("A", "B"),
  value = c(1, 2)
) %>% 
  addHtmlTableStyle(css.cell = c("color: red;", 
                                 "color: blue;")) %>% htmlTable(rnames = FALSE)
```